# "Possible duplicate" comment is not appearing when I vote to close

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

Starting a few days ago, when I vote to close a question as a duplicate, I don't see the auto comment when I'm returned to the question. I have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: Lol. The irony! :P